# Why the image source is not revcieved correctly in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I am trying to get the sources of some images from a `data.js` file that acts like a database, just for learning purpose. I am exporting an array of objects, and among the proprieties of each object is a `coverImg` propriety that stores the source of the image.

When I import the array into the App.js file and map over this array I return a component that has one of the attributes img (the image source)

Even though I get no error like: "Cannot find the image"

The only way it works is with import the source itself with `import imgSource from './images/image.png'`, but I wanna do it with `.map()`, mapping through that array that comes after importing the array of objects from `data.js`.

This is the way I do it:

```
import React from "react";

import data from './data';

export default function App() {
const cards = data.map(card => {
    return <Card
        key={card.id}
        name={card.name}
        img={card.coverImg}
        rating={card.stats.rating}
        reviewCount={card.stats.reviewCount}
        country={card.location}
        title={card.title}
        price={card.price}
    />
});

return (
    <div>
        {cards}
    </div>
)
```

}

And this is the `data.js` file:

```
export default [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Life Lessons with Katie Zaferes",
    description: "I will share with you what I call \"Positively Impactful Moments of Disappointment.\" Throughout my career, many of my highest moments only came after setbacks and losses. But learning from those difficult moments is what gave me the ability to rise above them and reach my goals.",
    price: 136,
    coverImg: "./images/katie-zafares.jpg",
    stats: {
        rating: 5.0,
        reviewCount: 6
    },
    location: "Online",
    openSpots: 0,
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Learn Wedding Photography",
    description: "Interested in becoming a wedding photographer? For beginner and experienced photographers alike, join us in learning techniques required to leave the happy couple with memories that'll last a lifetime.",
    price: 125,
    coverImg: "./images/wedding-photography.png",
    stats: {
        rating: 5.0,
        reviewCount: 30
    },
    location: "Online",
    openSpots: 27,
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: "Group Mountain Biking",
    description: "Experience the beautiful Norwegian landscape and meet new friends all while conquering rugged terrain on your mountain bike. (Bike provided!)",
    price: 50,
    coverImg: "./images/mountain-bike.png",
    stats: {
        rating: 4.8,
        reviewCount: 2
    },
    location: "Norway",
    openSpots: 3,
}
```

]

And the Card component:

```
import React from 'react';
import star from '../images/star.png';

import star from '../images/star.png';


export default function Card(props) {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <img src={props.img} alt={props.name}/>
            <div>
                <div className="score">
                    <img src={star} alt="star"/>
                    <strong>{props.rating}</strong>
                    <p className="faded-font">({props.reviewCount}) • {props.country}</p>
                </div>
                <p>{props.title}</p>
                <strong>
                    From ${props.price} <p className="faded-font" id="person"> / person</p>
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

P.S: The `images/` folder is inside the `src/` folder

Comment: Referencing the image by its project file path only works if you import/require it, webpack will then add the image to the output. If you don't import the images you need to use a (relative) URL, i.e. `coverImg: "mountain-bike.png"` and `<img src={"/images/" + props.img} />` then move the images folder inside the `public` folder. (this is because React doesn't matter in this case and the browser simply tries to load the image via the URL, so it needs to be visible; the file system isn't)

Comment: Actually I logged out the image source for every component.
I hard coded on instance of that component using " import imgSource from './images/image.png' ".
The hard coded image source is:
/static/media/image.c214569a3f6f84cb5b8a.jpg

Comment: Exactly, this happens when webpack adds the image because you imported it. Again, not necessary. Move them to the public folder and use the URL starting with a slash.